# Use ES6 Proxy to observe objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can I use ES6 Proxy to observe object, getting and setting properties etc?
For example:

```
var obj = {a: 1; b: 2};
obj.a = 3; // I need to catch this setting, like a Object.watch() in Firefox
```

Comment: Yes you can. You can learn about proxies on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's part of what they're for. The trap you're looking for is called `set`:

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
let p = new Proxy(obj, {
  set(target, name, value) {
    console.log("set " + name + " to " + value);
    target[name] = value;
  }
});
p.a = 3;
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't handle setting value to `obj.a` directly.

Comment: @KesantieluDasefern: No, of course not. To handle that, you'd have to modify `obj` (e.g., install a getter/setter combination), and it would be property-specific. AFAIK, there are no plans for `Object.watch`-like functionality; too much of a performance impact relative to utility.

Comment: Actually Object.observe was planned for ES7, but they decided to support proxies instead.

Answer (score -1):

Why not to use getters/setters of object?

```
let ourObj = {
    get a(){
        return this._a;
    }
    set a(val){
        console.log(val);
        this._a = val
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about using getters/setters on already existing properties?